# How to create a translucent, glowing image of code at a perspective using Adobe Fireworks CS6?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I like very much this kind of images, with code or with handwriting...

Could you guide me how to do this kind of images?

In two parts:

- **How can I create the text with a warped perspective?**
- **How can I create the multi-layered, glassy effect of the background?**

Thank You.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably a few different ways of doing this, and in different programs. This is how I would do it:

- CODE: Start with a **color background**, and add a **text layer/s** with the code in white.
- TRANSPARENT CODE BEHIND: Either duplicate your **text** layer or create a new one, apply a gaussian **blur** to it and make it semi-transparent (30% or so)
- PICTURE BLUR: Use a manual tool to **blur the edges of the picture** like in your last sample (will edit details into this step soon!).
- SHADOWS: Manually add a **shadow** (you can again use the black brush and the blur tool) in the sides/ends.

A very quick, dirty sample to get you started:

[image]

Comment: thank you. Do you know how to make that effect of blue and violet image??  a king of fog where there are areas with color and other sithout colors